# How do i tell if i'm in the debugger under android?

Tags: android, debugging

I need a way to check whether or not my android app is currently being debugged (there's a condition we check for on startup that I specifically do -not- want to check when the debugger is running).  Does such a beast exist?

Comment: Found it - android.os.Debug has methods that I can use for this.

Answer (score 24):

You need to look at [isDebuggerConnected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#isDebuggerConnected()).

But it is considered a very bad practice to make your application's behavior dependent on whether debugger connected or not. This may lead to some hard to catch bugs. So be careful.

Comment: This was specifically to perform some cleanup in the case of the app dying badly (e.g. a kill -9 in adb) - since the app dies badly when you start the debugger (it kills the old run of the app and starts a new one for debugging) I wanted to block putting up a notification of the bad exit, since I figured that would just annoy developers trying to debug.

Comment: Tiny app behavior may be different under debugger, in my case requesting "pretty formatted" xml resources from http calls when I debug, and getting condensed otherwise.

Comment: I use this in unitary tests, to increase the timeout value when the debugger is connected. This way the tests can pass even if the execution time is increased due to breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I can use android.os.Debug's isDebuggerConnected and waitingForDebugger methods to catch this state.

Comment: +1 It also has the helpful hint, that there is a `waitingForDebugger` method for when your code is run before the debugger is connected. All this comes in very handy when debugging test cases in a concurrent thread situation to define timeouts.